# Kendo UI Scheduler not binding resources properly

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm having trouble trying to get my KendoUI Scheduler resources to populate correctly. I haven't found a good example of how to bind a nested JSON object (in this case Task and User listed in the screenshot) to resources that are fetched.

Also while running Fiddler, it seems like the resources listed below aren't even fetched from the web service. The documentation is super unclear on some of the specifics and I'm having a hard time finding the problem.

The schedule actually pulls back all the SchedulerEvents (the JSON fetched below) and shows me events bound to the Schedule properly, just they have no resources attached. Right now all of my webservice calls are running off localhost so JSONP shouldn't be required yet as my service calls are all calling "localhost".

I did find something similar to what I'm trying to do with projection of data [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) via Telerik's documentation, but I haven't been able to figure out a good solution yet.

**Edited** : updated my question with individual DataSource code

**Edited 2** : I should also mention since posting this, the JSON screenshot isn't entirely accurate anymore as I've taken `ScheduledTaskId` and `UserId` (the two identifying properties of my Task and User resources I'm trying to add to appointments) and made that property available directly from my SchedulerEvent class to avoid nesting objects.

### Javascript

```
//Datasources code has been moved to here. Explicitly fetching data and assigning to Resources datasource properties

$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()"),
    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
    views: [
        "day",
        { type: "week", selected: true },
        "month",
        "agenda"
    ],
    dataSource: {

        batch: true,

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "ServiceURI/Schedule/Get",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },

        resources: [
            {
                field: "userId",
                title: "User",
                dataTextField: "displayName",
                dataValueField: "userId",
                dataSource: userDataSource
            }
            {
                field: "scheduledTaskId",
                title: "Task",
                dataTextField: "taskName",
                dataValueField: "scheduledTaskId",
                dataSource: taskDataSource
            }
        ],
        schema: {

            model: {
                id: "shiftId",
                fields: {
                    shiftId: {
                        from: "ShiftId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    title: {
                        from: "Title",
                        validation: { required: true } 
                    },
                    start: {
                        from: "Start",
                        type: "date",
                        validation: { required: true } 
                    },
                    end: {
                        from: "End",
                        type: "date",
                        validation: { required: true }
                    },
                    scheduledTaskId: {
                        from: "ScheduledTaskId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    userId: {
                        from: "UserId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    description: { 
                        from: "Description"
                    },
                    recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                    recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                    recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### Datasources

```
var userDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            //This should be a customized list of users, or all users fetched from the datastore
            url: "ServiceURI/UserProfile/Get/",
            dataType: "json"
        },
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "userId",
            fields: {
                userId: {
                    from: "UserId",
                    type: "number"
                },
                displayName: {
                    from: "DisplayName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
userDataSource.fetch();

var taskDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {
        read: {
            //This should be the entire list of tasks fetched from the datastore
            url: "ServiceURI/ScheduledTask/Get?companyId=1",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "scheduledTaskId",
            fields: {
                scheduledTaskId: {
                    from: "ScheduledTaskId",
                    type: "number"
                },
                taskName: {
                    from: "TaskName"
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
taskDataSource.fetch();
```

### JSON returned

[image: JSON]

Comment: You will need to retrieve the resources before the Scheduler is loaded, as resources are required for rendering of scheduler in the view. If you can fetch the Resources values then the best option is to retrive them in the controller and pass then to View via ViewBag or ViewData.

Comment: Then what's the point of having a client-side datasource if I can't fetch and bind it when the kendoScheduler is built?

Comment: Even to simplify it further, I tried creating separate DataSource objects, and then tried to fetch them after creation and assign them to the Scheduler object. I put the newly added "DataSources" code above the KendoScheduler init and it still hasn't worked... updated my question

Comment: If you wish to have Resources from the DataSource binding then the best option to achieve this is to create Scheduler on the Resources DataSource Request End. So that When Scheduler is initialized it has all the required values (i.e. Resources List). See the below Answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The resources object is inside of the dataSource object as I thought it was supposed to be per the documentation

```
views: [
    "day",
    { type: "week", selected: true },
    "month",
    "agenda"
],
dataSource: {
    resources: [
        {
            field: "userId",
            title: "User",
            dataTextField: "displayName",
            dataValueField: "userId",
            dataSource: userDataSource
        }
        {
            field: "scheduledTaskId",
            title: "Task",
            dataTextField: "taskName",
            dataValueField: "scheduledTaskId",
            dataSource: taskDataSource
        }
    ]
}
```

### Answer

Just need to move the resources array outside of the DataSource... works as expected without any explicit .fetch() statements either

```
views: [
    "day",
    { type: "week", selected: true },
    "month",
    "agenda"
],
resources: [
    {
        field: "userId",
        title: "User",
        dataTextField: "displayName",
        dataValueField: "userId",
        dataSource: userDataSource
    }
    {
        field: "scheduledTaskId",
        title: "Task",
        dataTextField: "taskName",
        dataValueField: "scheduledTaskId",
        dataSource: taskDataSource
    }
],
dataSource: { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**DataSource + Scheduler Creation**

```
var userDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            //This should be a customized list of users, or all users fetched from the datastore
            url: "ServiceURI/UserProfile/Get/",
            dataType: "json"
        },
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) {
        //Start Fetching Task Data Source
        taskDataSource.fetch();
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "userId",
            fields: {
                userId: {
                    from: "UserId",
                    type: "number"
                },
                displayName: {
                    from: "DisplayName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

> Task DataSource declaration.

```
var taskDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

    transport: {
        read: {
            //This should be the entire list of tasks fetched from the datastore
            url: "ServiceURI/ScheduledTask/Get?companyId=1",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    requestEnd: function(e) {
        //Once Task and User DataSource have been fetched, create the Scheduler
        createScheduler(e);
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "scheduledTaskId",
            fields: {
                scheduledTaskId: {
                    from: "ScheduledTaskId",
                    type: "number"
                },
                taskName: {
                    from: "TaskName"
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

---

```
function createScheduler(e){

  $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      date: new Date("@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()"),
      timezone: "Etc/UTC",
      views: [
        "day",
        { type: "week", selected: true },
        "month",
        "agenda"
    ],
    dataSource: {

        batch: true,

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "ServiceURI/Schedule/Get",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },

        resources: [
            {
                field: "userId",
                title: "User",
                dataTextField: "DisplayName",
                dataValueField: "UserId",
                dataSource: userDataSource
            }
            {
                field: "scheduledTaskId",
                title: "Task",
                dataTextField: "TaskName",
                dataValueField: "ScheduledTaskId",
                dataSource: taskDataSource
            }
        ],
        schema: {

            model: {
                id: "shiftId",
                fields: {
                    shiftId: {
                        from: "ShiftId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    title: {
                        from: "Title",
                        validation: { required: true } 
                    },
                    start: {
                        from: "Start",
                        type: "date",
                        validation: { required: true } 
                    },
                    end: {
                        from: "End",
                        type: "date",
                        validation: { required: true }
                    },
                    scheduledTaskId: {
                        from: "ScheduledTaskId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    userId: {
                        from: "UserId",
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    description: { 
                        from: "Description"
                    },
                    recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                    recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                    recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

> Start the DataSources fetching from User Source then Task Source and finally creation of the Scheduler.

```
userDataSource.fetch();
```

I have never tried this before, but I think above would work as per your requirement.

Comment: It successfully calls all of the read URLs, but still the Scheduler is created without the necessary resources attached. This is very disappointing this approach can't be used. I am going to try fetching all of my resources and passing it via ViewBag and see how that works. The only other reason I can think why it isn't working is due to a binding issue on the schema mapping, but I have no idea how to even begin debugging that and the console doesn't log any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is binding Case. In your Datasources for the resource Objects, you have a model definition, taking items from your JSON data and transforming it into a Model:

```
var userDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            //This should be a customized list of users, or all users fetched from the datastore
            url: "ServiceURI/UserProfile/Get/",
            dataType: "json"
        },
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "userId",
            fields: {
                userId: {
                    from: "UserId",
                    type: "number"
                },
                displayName: {
                    from: "DisplayName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In your scheduler Binding, you are setting the dataTextField and dataValueField to:

```
{
    field: "userId",
    title: "User",
    dataTextField: "DisplayName",
    dataValueField: "UserId",
    dataSource: userDataSource
}
```

Notice that your model is `displayName` and `userId`, but your resource Bindings are `DisplayName` and `UserId` - By the time you are binding into the Scheduler resource collection, the data has been transformed into your model schema, and casing is important.

If you correct the casing, that should solve your issue. You will also need to ensure that both Datasources are populated prior to creating the Scheduler object.

Comment: I will try this this morning! I may have tried it already since I've tried so much else as well. Thanks!

Comment: Nope didn't work. My most recent code has changed those properties to match the schema for the model and still doesn't bind correctly.

Comment: Do you see the Resource section appear in the popup, they just aren't selected? And does the drop-down contain the resources you are binding , or is it empty?